# Zooming in R ggplot2: How to avoid clipping with untouched unevenly spaced log10 gridlines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2 I have a spectrum with unevenly spaced vertical gridlines in log10:

```
freq <- 10^seq(2, 4, by  = 0.1)
d <- rnorm(length(freq))
data <- data.frame(freq, d)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = freq, y = d)) + coord_trans(x = "log10") + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1000*seq(1,10,by = 2))
```

My objective is to zoom into a certain region of the plot.

`scale_x_continuous()` shows clipping removing unseen data points. However, the vertical gridlines are not changed:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = freq, y = d)) + coord_trans(x = "log10") + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3000, 8000), breaks = 1000*seq(1,10,by = 2))
```

There is no clipping with `coord_cartesian()`, but the vertical gridlines got modified and evenly spaced:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = freq, y = d)) + coord_trans(x = "log10") + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1000*seq(1,10,by = 2)) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(3000, 8000))
```

How can I avoid both clipping and keep the original unevenly spaced log10 vertical gridlines?

Comment: Setting the limits in `coord_trans()` solves the issue: `ggplot(data = data, aes(x = freq, y = d)) + coord_trans(x = "log10", limx = c(3000, 8000)) + geom_line() +
+     scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1000*seq(1,10,by = 2))`